# Behavior of google cloud end point api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I defined a google cloud end point using java. the class method annotations looks like:

```
@Api(
    name = "instaSmartApi",
    version = "v1",
    )
public class InstaSmartSvc {
@ApiMethod(name = "analyzeImage")
      public Message analyzeImage(@Named("imgURL") String imgURL) {
...
}
```

I call it using curl which works is:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"imgUrl" : "www.google.com"}' https://instasmarttagger.appspot.com/_ah/api/instaSmartApi/v1/analyzeImage/abc.jpg
```

this works fine except it ignores what i passed in request body.

The way I was expecting it to work:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"imgUrl" : "www.google.com"}' https://instasmarttagger.appspot.com/_ah/api/instaSmartApi/v1/analyzeImage
```

But this returns not found. I am not sure why i have to append the method parameter in the end to make it work. Ideally i should pass that in the body. Please advise

Comment: Have you updated your app.yaml file? with the required configuration? as given in the following link 
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/get-started-app-engine#java
and following the open api specification 
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/tree/master/examples/v2.0/